# Rendering Engine -> Inverted questionmark for \cdot (multiplication sign) on WINDOWS10

Tags: rendering

I'll try to explain my problem:

I am using Latex in an editor that creates items. Later these items are rendered on a client application with a gecko rendering engine (= what is presented is a computerized psychological test).

The multiplication sign (\cdot) is now shown as an inverted question mark, but only on Windows 10, whereas Windows 7 is fine and I get the  ⋅

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that the tex markup is being interpreted by the browser, eg MathJax or katex? if so it is off topic here as they do not use TeX

Comment: The tex markup as well as html5, css, js, stylesheets [...] are being interpreted by an application (not a *browser* like firefox).
And the strange thing is, there are no problems with rendering on our testing computer (also windows 10)... is it possible that I have to adjust settings in windows 10? I'm a bit lost and not the programmer of that application, sorry :D

Comment: but what is "the application" it does not sound like it is TeX (TeX can not process css or javascript) so it appears to be off topic. How can anyone tell you if "that application" has adjustable settings if you do not say what application it is?